# Random String Generator Javascript - While Loop

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a random letter generator with a "while" loop.  It's return one value into the randomString and then quits the loop.

```js
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var randomString = "";

while (randomString.length < 6) {
  console.log(randomString += alpha.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)));

  randomString++;
}
```

Returns one value from alpha string to `randomString` and then quits the loop instead of going on for 4 more loops - condition set at `(randomString.length < 6)`.

Comment: Idk what `randomString++` is going to do on a string - but that might be an issue. (It returns `NaN`)

Comment: why do you use the randomString++ function? This sets for adding a number on top of it's older value. you can delete this line

Comment: In other words, just get rid of `randomString++;`

Answer (score 2):

Incrementing a string results in `NaN`, which doesn't have a `length` property, so the loop ends after one iteration.

Don't increment your `randomString`:

```js
  var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  var randomString = "";

  while (randomString.length < 6) {
    console.log(randomString += alpha.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a variable and set is an empty string. Then, create a `while` loop that will continually add new random letters to this string, as long as the string length is less than 6 or any length you choose. `+=` operator to add a new letter to the end of the string.

```js
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "" // first, create an empty string

while (randomString.length < 6) {
    console.log(randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]);
    randomString++;
}
```